# Get current task ID in Spark in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark

I need to get the ID of the current task in Spark. I have been searching in Google and in the official API but the only IDs I can find are the executor ID and the ID of the RDD. Does anyone know how to get the unique ID of a task? I have seen that the class `TaskInfo` has exactly what I am looking for, but I do not know how to get an instance of this class.

Answer (score 14):

In order to get the specific task ID you can use the [TaskContext](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/TaskContext.html#taskAttemptId()):

```
import org.apache.spark.TaskContext;

textFile.map( x -> {
    TaskContext tc = TaskContext.get();
    System.out.println(tc.taskAttemptId());
});
```

Bear in mind that the specific println will be printed on the node it is currently executed and not the drivers console.

Comment: Can we get taskContext in a  Java reflect way ?

Comment: I suppose you can, but why would you need reflection at this point?