# Get task id of an executor's task in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `rdd.foreachPartition(some_function)` action in pyspark.
The `some_function` function writes data of the current task in the executor to a file in a location that is common to all the executors(like hdfs or s3 bucket).

Now, if I use the same filename across all the executors, the file get replaced and left with only the last written file. So I am looking for a unique identifier to represent each task and thereby represent each filename.

I was interested in the task ID as that is unique. But could not find anywhere, how to get the task ID in pyspark. I found something [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33561435/7103409) in scala/java but not in pyspark.

Update: As suggested, I checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31632343/7103409). However, that gives the stageID while I was interested at taskID of individual tasks inside every stage. The stageId answer is also a good info to know though.

Comment: How using a random uuid in the file name?

Comment: Do you feel that it is going to be unique across all the executors and even when the executors have to process new chunk of data?

Comment: That's the most likely to guarantee uniqueness that I know. Check the collision section on this page for an idea: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

Comment: Thanks Ernest. This opened up for new logic. However, I would keep the question still open as I am curious to find out if there is a way to get task id, and also for the reason that uniqueness of the uuid is not completely guaranteed (Though I am convinced that the id being not unique is extremely rare case).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get ID of a map task in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31631791/how-to-get-id-of-a-map-task-in-spark)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem a while back.

I solved it by using `datetime.now()` in the file name and to be absolutely sure I will not get the same file names I also used :

```
rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(lambda x,y: (x,y), preservesPartitioning = True).foreachPartition(lambda x: some_function(x))
```

This will give you a unique partition id at x[0] that you can add to any filename to insure uniqueness

Comment: Looking at your suggestion, I realized that we don't even need any unique value generators like datetime.now() or uuid(). Just the partition index should be good enough.

Thanks for the answer.